# How to compare value in array?

Tags: java, arrays

how to compare value in an array?

I have array named list which contains 12 elements. I see if value in index 0 is equal or not equal to value in index 2.

I have tried this code but it doesnt seems to work.

```
if ((list.get(0)==list.get(2) && list.get(1)==list.get(3)) 
{
   System.out.println("equal")
}
```

Comment: "it doesnt seems to work" is not a very good problem report :-) You need to give more details - what does it do? Does it even compile? Does it just not print "equal"? Etc, etc.

Comment: keep in mind that == is different than equals(Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(list[0] == list[2] && list[1] == list[3]){
    System.out.println("equal");
}
```

If they are strings:

```
if(list[0].equals(list[2]) && list[1].equals(list[3])){
    System.out.println("equal");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If it's *really* an array, you want:

```
if (list[0] == list[2] && list[1] == list[3])
```

Note that if the array is of reference types, that's comparing by reference identity rather than for equality. You might want:

```
if (list[0].equals(list[2])) && list[1].equals(list[3]))
```

Although that will then go bang if any of the values is null. You might want a helper method to cope with this:

```
public static objectsEqual(Object o1, Object o2)
{
    if (o1 == o2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return o1.equals(o2);
}
```

Then:

```
if (objectsEqual(list[0], list[2]) && objectsEqual(list[1], list[3]))
```

If you've really got an `ArrayList` instead of an array then all of the above still holds, just using `list.get(x)` instead of `list[x]` in each place.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Thats really help. but how if instead of looking for equality, I wanted to check if the elements is not equal? can I just use  if (! (objectsEqual(list[0], list[2]) && objectsEqual(list[1], list[3])))

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing object references, not objects themselves. You need to use a method call. All classes inherit `equals()` from the root `Object` class, so it might work:

```
if(list.get(0).equals(list.get(2)) && list.get(1).equals(list.get(3)))
{
   System.out.println("equal");
}
```

[This article](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) seems to be a good summary of other comparison methods available.